# Rust libraries made with PyO3 and rust-cpython won't import when running pytest

Tags: python, rust, pytest, pyo3

While following various tutorials on compiling Rust libraries for further import from Python (I've tried both [PyO3](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3) and [rust-cpython](https://github.com/dgrunwald/rust-cpython)), I've been able to build a simple libary and successfully import it from my `main.py` and interactive Python shells.

However, when trying to test and benchmark pure Python vs. my Rust library, I consistently get import errors:

```
_____________________________________________ ERROR collecting main.py _____________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/xxx/pyo3/sumlib/main.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
main.py:1: in <module>
    import sumlib
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sumlib'
```

Again, the library imports just fine from the main python file and the interactive shells like `IPython`.

I'm on macOS Big Sur, Python 3.8 installed using `pyenv`. Here is my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "sumlib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "sumlib"
# "cdylib" is necessary to produce a shared library for Python to import from.
#
# Downstream Rust code (including code in `bin/`, `examples/`, and `tests/`) will not be able
# to `use string_sum;` unless the "rlib" or "lib" crate type is also included, e.g.:
# crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[dependencies.pyo3]
version = "0.14.2"
features = ["extension-module"]
```

Everything else is very trivial, from the `PyO3` and `rust-cpython`, to the same result.

Comment: How are you packaging your module? There's [a section on packaging tools](https://pyo3.rs/master/building_and_distribution.html#packaging-tools) in the `PyO3` docs.

Comment: I'm basically following the instructions, for example, I used `maturin` + a virtual envirnoment for `PyO3`, and it generates and installs valid wheels, but it still can't seem to import my compiled dynamic library specifcally from `pytest`.

Answer (score 1):

tl/dr: Invoke your tests using `python -m pytest` instead of `pytest`.

---

It sounds like you haven't installed your Python extension module (eg, using `pip install`) and are instead relying on it being inside your working directory. This would allow you to import it using an interpreter or `main.py` launched via `python -m`,

```sh
$ tree .
.
├── bin
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── sumlib.py
└── examples
    └── main.py

2 directories, 3 files
$ ipython --no-banner

In [1]: from bin import sumlib

In [2]: exit()

$ python -m examples.main
Successfully imported sumlib!
```

but not using `pytest examples/main.py` or `python examples/main.py`.

```sh
$ pytest examples/main.py
======================================================= test session starts =======================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: ...
plugins: typeguard-2.10.0
collected 0 items / 1 error

============================================================= ERRORS ==============================================================
________________________________________________ ERROR collecting examples/main.py ________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '.../examples/main.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
.../python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
examples/main.py:5: in <module>
    from bin import sumlib
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bin'
...
$ python examples/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bin import sumlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bin'
```

This is because `ipython` and `python -m` both add the current directory, which contains your extension module, to Python's `sys.path`, but `pytest examples/main.py` and `python examples/main.py` don't. (See the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/pythonpath.html#invoking-pytest-versus-python-m-pytest).) You can solve this by either installing your extension module or running your tests using `python -m pytest` instead of `pytest`.